# How to find the regions for the IOS Store app release?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

For downloading IOS app store reviews and ratings we are using iTunes apple API which is region-specific.
https://itunes.apple.com/**REGION**/rss/customerreviews/**id=xxxxxxx**/sortby=mostrecent/page=1/json

Is there any way to find all the regions where the app has been released? So that we will download the reviews and ratings for specific regions.

Thanks in advance.